# How to set priority in priority encoder?

Tags: digital-logic

If I have four inputs D0, D1, D2 and D3 and I want to give priority to D2, then how would I design with my priority encoder? Similarly if my priority is D1 then what should I do?

Comment: Are you asking how to _design_ a priority encoder that ignores other inputs and always outputs the number 2 if D2 is active?

Comment: Just connect the input you want to have highest priority to the highest priority input of the encoder.

Comment: Do you want a STATIC priority encoder (the same input has always highest priority) or a DYNAMIC one. (There is an extra signal which tells what the highest priority should be.)?

Comment: @user3535598 -- there is also the possibility of "rotating priority" (i.e. the last input asserted has the lowest priority, with the other priorities bumped up by one to match)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming inputs are active high.  If not, you may invert them or select different gates below.

Start by generating a set of 4 signals N1-N3 indicating whether the highest single priority input is inactive, or both of the top two, or all of the top three.  Think "nor" gates.

From that, determine for each input whether is is active while all higher-priority inputs are inactive.  Think "and" gates.

If you want a binary-coded output, identify for each bit position whether there are any inputs whose code should have a "1" in that position, which are active at the same time as all higher-priority inputs are inactive.  Think "or" gates.

If you need to be able to e.g. have a priority-reversing input, that should be handled with logic placed before the first set of "nor" gates.  Instead of feeding "nor" gates direct from the priority-encoder inputs, generate a set of signals that means e.g. "input #3 is active, and it should have priority over #2".  Feed the "nor" gate associated with each input with all the signals that would indicate that a higher-priority input is active.

This approach may not always yield the minimum possible amount of circuitry, but it is straightforwardly adaptable to a wide range of requirements, and does not impose any particular relationship between priority and output encoding.